# Custom UITabbar ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create a `UITabBar` like Instagram's. It seems unusual because the selected item and middle item have background colors that take up the entire cell. Do I need to create a custom `UITabBar` or can I provide images to the built in `UITabBarController` to replicate this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can build a subclass of UITabBarController, then put these code in viewWillAppear.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{ 

for (NSInteger i = 1; i<= 5 ; i ++) {
    UIViewController *VC = self.viewControllers[i-1];

    UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TabBar%d",i]] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];;
    UIImage *selImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TabBar%dSel",i]] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    UITabBarItem *item = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:nil image:image selectedImage:selImage];
    item.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
    VC.tabBarItem = item;
    item.tag = i-1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try 3.party [**M13InfiniteTabBar**](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13InfiniteTabBar).

It helps you save your time. You just custom base on it.